# How to consume rest service from https?

Tags: wcf, rest, https

hi i wish to publish my rest service in .net to a https:// server.. do i have to make any change in it so that to consume it in my asp.net application?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a service hosted on IIS then you really just need to do something like [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx).  You may also need to change some of the binding config.

Your service implementation will not have to change.